# Error while splitting unsigned int into unsigned char[]

Tags: c

I am trying to split an unsigned int into the numbers into places: for example the number 234 becomes in the unsigned char array {0,0,0,2,3,4} and i am seeing strange effects , i am not sure i am doing it the right way, is there a better one?

here is the code i am using now:

```
         void display_decl(unsigned int j)
         {
             unsigned char lst[6];

             lst[5] = j & 0x0f;
             lst[4] = j >> 4 & 0x0f;
             lst[3] = j >> 8 & 0x0f;
             lst[2] = j >> 12 & 0x0f;
             lst[1] = j >> 16 & 0x0f;
             lst[0] = j >> 20 & 0x0f;

             display_digits(lst);

         }
```

Comment: a decimal digit is not 4 bits. It would work if the number was `0x234`

Comment: As it is not packed binary-coded decimal, use powers of 10. Also, if you want characters suitable for presentation, add `'0'` after isolating the decimal digit.

Comment: The shifts above will give you hexadecimal digits, not base-10 ones, and there should be 8 of them. To get decimal digits, you need to divide by 10 and keep the remainders. Also, I don't see what display_digits() is doing, but somewhere you have to convert the digits into ASCII to display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split a number into `char` code needs use the intended base and null character terminate to treat as a string.

```
#include <limits.h>

void display_decl(unsigned int j) {
  char lst[sizeof j * CHAR_BIT + 1];
  unsigned base = 10;  // or 16 or any base 2 to 16
  char *p = &lst[sizeof lst] - 1;
  *p = '\0';
  do {
    p--;
    *p = "0123456789ABCDEF"[j%base];
    j /= base;
  } while (j > 0);
  display_string(p);
}
```